# Convert json file into csv encode/decode problems

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, yelp

My semester project is about classification by using Naive bayes. I ve decided to use Yelp dataset. While I was turning the json file into csv file I came up with couple of problems. Such as :

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Its because of the wrong usage of json.loads(). I tried a couple of deifferent usage of the function to manage this part of the program. Unfortunately, none of them worked. I put my code down below,  if you have any idea about how to handle this, can you please explain it to me?
`

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
import codecs
global df
global s
global count

def convert(x):
    ob = json.loads(x)
    for k, v in ob.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            ob[k] = ','.join(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for kk, vv in v.items():
                ob['%s_%s' % (k, kk)] = vv
            del ob[k]
    return ob


s = ""
count = 0
for json_filename in glob('*.json'):
    csv_filename = '%s.csv' % json_filename[:-5]
    print('Converting %s to %s' % (json_filename, csv_filename))
    with open('yelp_dataset_challenge_round9.json','rb') as f: #open in binary mode
        for line in f:
            for cp in ('cp1252', 'cp850'):
                try:
                    if count is 0:
                        count = 1
                    else:
                        s = str(line.decode('utf-8'))
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    pass
    df = pd.DataFrame([convert(s)])
    df.to_csv(csv_filename, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

`

Thanks in advance :)